# Ubuntu 22.04 linux-firmware initramfs-tools install error while apt upgrade

Tags: apt, kernel, initramfs

i am getting this persistent error while performing updates

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-50-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-50-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 initramfs-tools
```